# How to get and set text to an EditText in GridView in Android?

Tags: android

I have a GridView that displays matrix element and each of the element consists of an EditText and a TextView object.

how can I get access to a specific EditText and TextView object in the GridView?

I want to get and set text to EditText and TextView object dynamically. I have developed some code to set text to EditText row+col and to TextView (row, col) but all the EditText show 2 and all TextView show (1,1) Please check my code and help me, I will very thankful to you.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context mContext;

        TextView elementSubscript;
        EditText elementValue ;
        int matrixIndex =0;


        public GridAdapter(Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View elementLayout;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                elementLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.matrix_element, null);

                elementSubscript = (TextView)elementLayout.findViewById(R.id.elementSubscript);
                elementValue = (EditText)elementLayout.findViewById(R.id.elementValue);

                for(int row=1; row<=5; row++)
                {
                    for(int col=1; col<=4; col++)
                    {
                        if(position == matrixIndex)
                        {
                            int mIndex =row+col;
                            elementSubscript.setText("( "+row+","+col+" )");
                            elementValue.setText(mIndex+"");

                            matrixIndex++;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                elementLayout = convertView;
            }

            return elementLayout;
        }


        public int getCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 20;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the recycled views. Please go through a proper tutorial [like this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). Check the section 5.5

Modified code:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context mContext;

    TextView elementSubscript;
    EditText elementValue ;
    int matrixIndex =0;


    public GridAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        View elementLayout = convertView;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();//If view is null inflate a view
            elementLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.matrix_element, null);
        }
            elementSubscript = (TextView)elementLayout.findViewById(R.id.elementSubscript);
            elementValue = (EditText)elementLayout.findViewById(R.id.elementValue);

            for(int row=1; row<=5; row++)
            {
                for(int col=1; col<=4; col++)
                {
                    if(position == matrixIndex)
                    {
                        int mIndex =row+col;
                        elementSubscript.setText("( "+row+","+col+" )");
                        elementValue.setText(mIndex+"");

                        matrixIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
      //updating the view in case of view reuse and new view
        return elementLayout;
    }


    public int getCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 20;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear I have no idea about recycled views. could you help me to recommend the changes where it's required in my code

Comment: i already made the changes for you. Inflate the view if convertView is null and always update the view. If the view is being recycled, convertView will have the old values which needs to be updated

Comment: Dear I have made the changes in my code but still not working